# 2D distributions in the HistFactory?

Tags: pyhf

How can I specify in the construction of the HistFactory the signal and background to be 2-dimensional distributions?

I have understood than in RooStats you need to change the TH1 to a TH2.

At the moment to write my model in the json file can I use a ndarray to do something similar?.

Which is the correct way to do this?

I hope someone can help me and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the best way is to unroll the distributions e.g.

```
{'data': 2darray.ravel().tolist()}
```

Since mathematically it  doesn't make any difference.

If you want to convert from XML+ROOT this is not yet supported (but could be). If so, please open an issue on GitHub.

Thanks for using pyhf!